# Ways to smoothly zoom in LibGDX?

Tags: java, math, libgdx

I'm building a LibGDX game and need to zoom the camera in and out. But when I do `camera.zoom = 1.2f;`, it just 'jumps' to that value. Instead, I want to have a smooth zoom.

**My question:**
What's the best way to smoothly zoom?

I want to zoom like this graph below. `y=0` is the start `cam.zoom`, `y=100` is the desired `cam.zoom` and the x-axis shows the time.
[image: Zoom graph]

Should I use `cam.zoom = f(time);`? (With some modification to `f(x)`)

> `time` is the total time passed since the beginning of the zoom.

Or is it better to use:

```
cam.zoom += (desiredZoom - cam.zoom) * delta * scalar;
```

> `delta` is the time between two frames and 
>  `scalar` is a float that will be adjusted in order to set the speed.

Or is there another, better way? What do you think?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: With second approach, camera.zoom will never reach desiredZoom, it will just infinitely get closer and closer to it. So use the first approach, and Interpolation, as @QBrute suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I know is use a countdown with an Interpolation.

```
// member variables:
float timeToCameraZoomTarget, cameraZoomTarget, cameraZoomOrigin, cameraZoomDuration;

private float zoomTo (float newZoom, float duration){
    cameraZoomOrigin = camera.zoom;
    cameraZoomTarget = newZoom;
    timeToCameraZoomTarget = cameraZoomDuration = duration;
}

// in render():
if (timeToCameraZoomTarget >= 0){
    timeToCameraZoomTarget -= deltaTime;
    float progress = timeToCameraZoomTarget < 0 ? 1 : 1f - timeToCameraZoomTarget / cameraZoomDuration;
    camera.zoom = Interpolation.pow3out.apply(cameraZoomOrigin, cameraZoomTarget, progress);        
}
```

You can replace `Interpolation.pow3out` with any of the functions [pictured here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MathUtils.[lerp](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html#lerp-float-float-float-) method.

**Example:**

```
MathUtils.lerp(currentZoom,targetZoom,progress);
```

Increase the progress value to change faster or lower to slow down speed the value changes.